# Prisma ORM query relation User

Tags: graphql, prisma, prisma-graphql

I'm trying to make to query 1:1 relation in Prisma ORM
But when querying it always returns null

Here is my datamodel:

```
enum Role {
  ADMIN
  MEMBER
  CONSTRIBUTOR
}

type User {
  id: ID! @id
  name: String! @unique
  email: String! @unique
  password: String!
  posts: [Post!]!
  role: Role @default(value: MEMBER)
}

type Post {
  id: ID! @id
  title: String
  excerpt: String
  content: Json
  author: User! @relation(link: INLINE)
}
```

Im trying to query a Post with Author that has a User in it:

but in my resolver when I do:

```
  getPost: async (parent, args, ctx, info) => {
            if (args.id) {
                console.log('GET POST by ID');
                const id = args.id;
                return await ctx.prisma.post({ id }).author();
            }
        },
```

It is always returning Null. Does someone know how can fix it ?

Comment: You're returning an author object, not a post object.

Comment: @DanielRearden But I want Post together with Author that is attached to that post :) How could I do that

Comment: Have you read [the docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/prisma-client/basic-data-access/reading-data-JAVASCRIPT-rsc2/#selecting-fields)?

Comment: @DanielRearden thank you will check the fragment api :)

Comment: @DanielRearden I thought querying for relation would be like this: https://www.prisma.io/tutorials/a-guide-to-common-resolver-patterns-ct08/#scenario:-implementing-relations-with-prisma-client

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by using sperate query for author like this:

```
   const author = await ctx.prisma.post({ id: id }).author();
   const post = await ctx.prisma.post({ id });

    return {
       ...post,
       author
    };
```